# Interesting test of Javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a Javascript RegExp test to detect date string format, I added an redundant "g" flag by mistake and found something interesting.

```js
var s = "2009/03/10";
var regex=/^\d{4}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{2}$/g;
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
```

I got a 'true' followed by a 'false', then another 'true', then another 'false'.

If I use a loop to execute it, I found something more interesting, I got four "true" in IE and Safari, and true,false,true,false in FF, Chrome.

```js
for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  var s = "2009/03/10";
  var regex=/^\d{4}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{2}$/g;
  alert(regex.test(s));
}
```

Does anybody has idea to explain why the Javascript regex behaves like that and what cause browsers return different results? ( related to variable declaration and life scope? )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use a global flag on a JS RegExp the "test" and "exec" methods each halt at the first match but keep a pointer to where they stopped searching in the string.  That pointer can be inspected on the `lastIndex` property.  When you call "test" or "exec" again it begins searching for a match starting at the `lastIndex`.

So, when you test a RegExp on a string that matches the entire string the lastIndex is set to the end of the string.  The next time you test it starts at the end of the string, returns `false`, and sets `lastIndex` back to zero.

The MDC has a [decent explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of this behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the MDC's explaination is very clear.

Comment: +1 thanks for the help, setting reg.lastIndex=0 before each test solved my problem.

Comment: It seems you can set lastIndex = 0 before each test if this is causing issues within a loop for instance.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this weird behavior don't use the global (g) flag.

This code should output: 'True','True','True','True'

```js
var s = "2009/03/10";
var regex=/^\d{4}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{2}$/i;
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
alert(regex.test(s));
```

The global (g) flat set the property RegExp.lastIndex. So each test() will start where the last one stopped.

For more info see documentation about [RegExp.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Comment: But what if I want the _g_ flag? For example to reuse the same regex in a _String.replace(regex,replacement)_ function? Without 'g' it replaces only the first occurence.

Comment: @DavidBalažic You could replace the regex with a function that creates a new regex object when you want to use it, that way there's no state persisting between uses.
`const s = "2009/03/10";`
`const regex = () => /^\d{4}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{2}$/ig;`

`alert(regex().test(s)) // true`
`alert(regex().test(s)) // true`
`alert(regex().test(s)) // true`