# Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the problem with this regular expression when I use the global flag and the case insensitive flag? Query is a user generated input. The result should be [true, true].

```
var query = 'Foo B';
var re = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
var result = [];
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
// result will be [true, false]
```

---

```js
var reg = /^a$/g;
for(i = 0; i++ < 10;)
   console.log(reg.test("a"));
```

Comment: Welcome to one of the many traps of RegExp in JavaScript. It has one of the worst interfaces to regex processing I've ever met, full of weird side-effects and obscure caveats. Most of the common tasks you typically want to do with regex are difficult to spell right.

Comment: XRegExp looks like a good alternative. http://xregexp.com/

Comment: See answer here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604860/interesting-test-of-javascript-regexp

Comment: One solution, if you can get away with it, is to use the regex literal directly instead of saving it to `re`.

Answer (score 465, accepted):

A `RegExp` object with the `g` flag keeps track of the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) where a match occurred, so on subsequent matches it will start from the last used index, instead of 0. Take a look:

```js
var query = 'Foo B';
var re = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
console.log(re.lastIndex);

console.log(re.test('Foo Bar'));
console.log(re.lastIndex);

console.log(re.test('Foo Bar'));
console.log(re.lastIndex);
```

If you don't want to manually reset `lastIndex` to 0 after every test, just remove the `g` flag.

Here's the algorithm that the specs dictate (section 15.10.6.2):

> **RegExp.prototype.exec(string)**
>
> Performs
> a regular expression match of string
> against the regular expression and
> returns an Array object containing the
> results of the match, or null if the
> string did not match The string
> ToString(string) is searched for an
> occurrence of the regular expression
> pattern as follows:

> 1. Let *R* be this RexExp object.
> 2. Let *S* be the value of ToString(string).
> 3. Let *length* be the length of *S*.
> 4. **Let lastIndex be the value of the lastIndex property on *R*.**
> 5. Let i be the value of ToInteger(lastIndex).
> 6. If the global property is false, let i = 0.
> 7. If i < 0 or i > length then set the *lastIndex* property of *R* to 0 and return null.
> 8. Call [[Match]], giving it the arguments S and i. If [[Match]]
>    returned failure, go to step 9;
>    otherwise let r be its State result
>    and go to step 10.
> 9. Let i = i+1.
> 10. Go to step 7.
> 11. Let e be r's endIndex value.
> 12. **If the global property is true, set the *lastIndex* property of *R* to e.**
> 13. Let n be the length of r's captures array. (This is the same
>     value as 15.10.2.1's
>     NCapturingParens.)
> 14. Return a new array with the following properties:
>
> - The index
>   property is set to the position of the
>   matched substring within the complete
>   string S.
> - The input property is set
>   to S.
> - The length property is set to
>   n + 1.
> - The 0 property is set to the
>   matched substring (i.e. the portion of
>   S between offset i inclusive and
>   offset e exclusive).
> - For each
>   integer i such that i > 0 and i ≤ n,
>   set the property named ToString(i) to
>   the ith element of r's captures array.

Comment: This is like Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy API design here.  "That pitfall that you fell in has been perfectly documented in the spec for several years, if you had only bothered to check"

Comment: Firefox's sticky flag doesn't do what you imply at all.  Rather, it acts as if there were a ^ at the start of the regular expression, EXCEPT that this ^ matches the *current* string position (lastIndex) rather than the start of the string.  You're effectively testing if the regex matches "right here" instead of "anywhere after lastIndex".  See the link you provided!

Comment: The opening statement of this answer is just not accurate. You highlighted step 3 of the spec which says nothing. The actual influence of `lastIndex` is in steps 5, 6 and 11. Your opening statement is only true IF THE GLOBAL FLAG IS SET.

Comment: @Prestaul yes, you're right that it doesn't mention the global flag. It was probably (can't remember what I thought back then) implicit due to the way the question is framed. Feel free to edit the answer or delete it and link to your answer. Also, let me reassure you that you're better than me. Enjoy!

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, sorry if my previous comment seemed attacky, that was not my intent. I can't edit it at this point, but I wasn't trying to shout, just to draw attention to the essential point of my comment. My bad!

Answer (score 88):

You are using a single `RegExp` object and executing it multiple times. On each successive execution it continues on from the last match index.

You need to "reset" the regex to start from the beginning before each execution:

```
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
re.lastIndex = 0;
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
// result is now [true, true]
```

Having said that it may be more readable to create a new RegExp object each time (overhead is minimal as the RegExp is cached anyway):

```
result.push((/Foo B/gi).test(stringA));
result.push((/Foo B/gi).test(stringB));
```

Comment: Or simply don't use the `g` flag.

Answer (score 43):

**`RegExp.prototype.test`** updates the regular expressions' **`lastIndex`** property so that each test will start where the last one stopped. I'd suggest using **`String.prototype.match`** since it doesn't update the **`lastIndex`** property:

```
!!'Foo Bar'.match(re); // -> true
!!'Foo Bar'.match(re); // -> true
```

Note: **`!!`** converts it to a boolean and then inverts the boolean so it reflects the result.

Alternatively, you could just reset the **`lastIndex`** property:

```
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
re.lastIndex = 0;
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
```

Answer (score 18):

Removing global `g` flag will fix your problem.

```
var re = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
```

*Should be*

```
var re = new RegExp(query, 'i');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the /g flag tells it to continue searching after a hit.

[If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Before your first search:

```
myRegex.lastIndex
//is 0
```

After the first search

```
myRegex.lastIndex
//is 8
```

Remove the g and it exits the search after each call to exec().

Comment: OP is not using `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set re.lastIndex = 0 because with g flag regex keep track of last match occured, so test will not go to test the same string, for that you need to do re.lastIndex = 0

```js
var query = 'Foo B';
var re = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
var result = [];
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));
re.lastIndex=0;
result.push(re.test('Foo Bar'));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the function:

```
function parseDevName(name) {
  var re = /^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$/g;
  var match = re.exec(name);
  return match.slice(1,4);
}

var rv = parseDevName("BR-H-01");
rv = parseDevName("BR-H-01");
```

The first call works.
The second call doesn't. The `slice` operation complains about a null value. I assume this is because of the `re.lastIndex`. This is strange because I would expect a new `RegExp` to be allocated each time the function is called and not shared across multiple invocations of my function.

When I changed it to:

```
var re = new RegExp('^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$', 'g');
```

Then I don't get the `lastIndex` holdover effect. It works as I would expect it to.