# email body getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: google-apps-script

The string from my gmail body message seems not to be working. I'm getting this error:

But when I'm using a static variable for html. I don't have any errors at all (I'm receiving the last success message 'SUCCESS but not found.. so this is still OK...' and that's what I wanted but I dont want to  use the static variable).

This is [the full source code in google app script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxFnn.png)

Please see  [this video for my demo.][2]

```
  [1]: https://pastebin.com/acBHN63S
  [2]: https://www.useloom.com/share/08525a017c574698a88f951cf04d7815
```

Error: [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxFnn.png)
Execution transcript from the editor:

```
[18-01-27 13:24:35:056 HKT] Starting execution
[18-01-27 13:24:35:079 HKT] SpreadsheetApp.getUi() [0.015 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:35:299 HKT] GmailApp.search([from:miikka.kukkosuo@gmail.com in:inbox, 0, 1]) [0.218 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:35:478 HKT] GmailThread.getMessages() [0.178 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:35:479 HKT] GmailMessage.getDate() [0 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:35:799 HKT] GmailMessage.getBody() [0.32 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:40:027 HKT] Ui.alert([Success! URL FOUND!: 
https://www.linnake.fi/e1t/c/*W7jytSj66jddKW1p_c9t3s4gsp0/*W3BkDbD4Xs7kfW4tJh-k19HByV0/5/f18dQhb0Sjv98XJ9RdW8C8HT52qwv1SV6bgdG2shkfGMf5pP-XD6prW7cmS1s8pCQ6vW25G0-N51_rSsW3Tmswx61]...) [4.227 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:40:108 HKT] UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://www.linnake.fi/e1t/c/*W7jytSj66jddKW1p_c9t3s4gsp0/*W3BkDbD4Xs7kfW4tJh-k19HByV0/5/f18dQhb0Sjv98XJ9RdW8C8HT52qwv1SV6bgdG2shkfGMf5pP-XD6prW7cmS1s8pCQ6vW25G0-N51_rSsW3Tmswx61SSZmW7mG7sD51vX4yW6HBR, {=}]...) [0.079 seconds]
[18-01-27 13:24:40:235 HKT] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from null. (line 51, file "Code") [5.152 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Use the code editor "Execution Transcript" to determine what line of code is producing the error.  We need to see the line of code that is producing the error.  Providing all the code is good, in case the context of the situation is needed, but posting the exact line of code that is the problem is the priority.  Read the troubleshooting guide:  [Apps Script troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: @SandyGood hi there, I added the execution transcript and screenshot of the error. thanks for your reply.

Comment: URL variable is null that's the problem. Can you check that html_body parameter you are passing in check_RD(html_body ) is exists?.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I replied to your comment and tried your suggestion please see video: https://www.useloom.com/share/7e8970c168404e859603c877ce21e1b0?focus_title=1&muted=1    -- I guess the new HTML found from the URL redirect does not work in regex. is there a way to reset regex? is that maybe the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer guys. replaced the regex /g flag to  /i

from this source: [Interesting test of Javascript RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604860/interesting-test-of-javascript-regexp)